# Как получить ширину React компонентов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

Подскажите - как я могу получить ширину g и text компонентов, чтобы потом на основе их значений вычислить нужный мне угол поворота для rotate.

```
const CustomizedAxisTock: React.FunctionComponent<ICustomTickProps> = ({x,y,payload,width,fill}) => {
        const firstLine = 12
        const secondLine = 24
        const dateTime = payload.value

    return (
        <g transform={`translate(${x},${y})`}>
            <text fontFamily="Roboto, sans-serif" transform={"rotate(-45)"} width={width} height="auto" textAnchor="middle" fontSize={12} fill={fill}>
            </text>
        </g>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Получить ссылки на дом элементы с помощью хука [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)
2. Отследить момент отрисовки на странице компонента в хуке [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)  и внутри обратиться к рефам и уже как обычного дом элемнта прочитать свойства.

Comment: Большое спасибо!